# Is there any online radio library or method out there?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, internet-radio, windows-mobile-5.0

One of my new programs that I'm thinking to develop is a online radio listener, but is there any library or method to do this? Thanks.

Comment: I am looking at writing a Radio Alarm Clock for some programming practice, did you have any luck with the BASS Library? I have never tried to include an external library before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [BASS](http://www.un4seen.com/) audio library supports [RTSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol).